# Controlling log4j output from ant

Tags: java, ant, log4j2

This is my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="debug">
   <appenders>
      <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
         <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
      </Console>
      <File name="LOGFILE" fileName="log/helloWorld.log">
         <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
      </File>
      <Asynch name="ASYNC">
         <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE"/>
         <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
      </Asynch>
   </appenders>
   <loggers>
      <root level="info">
         <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
      </root>
   </loggers>
</configuration>
```

And this is my build.xml:

```
<project default="helloWorld">
    <target name="helloWorld">
        <echo message="Hello World"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

The build.xml outputs one line, the logger is set to INFO.. but I see 87 lines of output in my log (only 14 lines of which appear to be INFO)! http://pastebin.com/6LMxLTge

What have I missed that lets all those DEBUGs come through?

Answer (score 1):

The following line configures Log4j 2 to log every "status event":

```
<configuration status="debug">
```

Instead, try the `error` level:

```
<configuration status="error">
```

[Log4j 2 Status Messages](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Status_Messages)

Comment: Hi @ChadN. I seem to be having a different problem now that is preventing me from testing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938533/using-log4j-2-with-ant-still-asking-for-lo4j-properties